# Span of the image of a vector under multiple matrix exponentials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ then I know that $\operatorname{span}\left(\left\{ e^{tA} v \mid t \in \mathbb R \right\}\right) = \operatorname{span}\left(\left\{ v, A v, A^2 v, \dots \right\}\right) = \operatorname{span}\left(\left\{ v, A v, A^2 v, \dots , A^{n-1} v \right\}\right)$.

I'm interested in a generalization of this. How can I explicitly compute in terms of $A, B \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ - not necessarily commuting - and $v \in \mathbb R^n$ what is $R(A, B, v) := \operatorname{span}\left(\left\{ e^{tA} e^{tB} v \mid t \in \mathbb R \right\}\right)$?

It's clear that

$$
R(A, B, v) \subseteq \operatorname{span}\left(\left\{ e^{tA} e^{sB} v \mid s, t \in \mathbb R \right\}\right) = \\
\operatorname{span}\left(\left\{ v, B v, \dots, B^{n-1} v, A v, A B v, \dots, A B^{n-1} v, A^2 v, \dots \dots , A^{n-1} B^{n-1} v \right\}\right)
$$

by repeated application of the case mentioned at the start of the question, but that is an overapproximation without a clear way of nailing down which subspace is part of the span I'm after.

Comment: Why do you claim that$$\operatorname{span}\left(\left\{ e^{tA} v\,\middle|\,t \in \mathbb R \right\}\right) = \operatorname{span}\left(\left\{ v, A v, A^2 v, \ldots \right\}\right)?$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos that the left set is a subset of the right should be clear. Note the right side is the smallest space closed under $A$ and containing $v$. To show that the left side is closed under $A$ take the derivative, or more specifically a sequence of the differences converging to the derivative which should work in a finite vector space. I was trying to find the related question that I'm sure have read some time in the past on SE but my google-fu is lacking right now.